# MYSQL Relationships and Query issue

Tags: php, mysql, relationship

User has many items but items have many categories.

I'm looking to display a table in the user account that finds the number of items for each item:

```
-------------------------------
| Item Name | Number of Items |
-------------------------------
|  Item 1   |        24       |
|  Item 2   |        18       |
|  Item 3   |        6        |
-------------------------------
```

I can't work it out... The user has multiple items but only one identifier in the user table

Does the User table have an item_id which then relates to user_items table? The user_items table has three fields: item_id, item name and number of items?

Anyone help a nublet out?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "*number of items for each item*"?  Had you meant "number of items for each user", or perhaps "number of users for each item"?  It's also not clear what (if anything) "categories" have to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If an item can "belong" to at most one user, just store directly in the `item` table a FK into the `user` table:

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE item (
    item_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    item_name VARCHAR(20),
    user_id   BIGINT UNSIGNED, -- NOT NULL if every item must belong to a user
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id)
  );
  ```

  Then, to fetch the number of items per user:

  ```sql
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS num_items FROM item GROUP BY user_id;
  ```

  If you wish also to fetch associated user information from the `user` table, you merely need perform a [SQL join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

  ```sql
  SELECT   user.*, COUNT(*) AS num_items
  FROM     user JOIN item USING (user_id)
  GROUP BY user_id;
  ```
- If an item can simultaneously "belong" to multiple users, store in your `user_items` table FKs into both the `user` and the `item` tables.

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE user_items (
    item_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item (item_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id)
  );
  ```

  Then to fetch the number of items per user:

  ```sql
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS num_items FROM user_items GROUP BY user_id;
  ```

  Or, conversely, the number of users per item:

  ```sql
  SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS num_users FROM user_items GROUP BY item_id;
  ```

  Again, you can perform a `JOIN` to fetch associated information from other table(s) as required.
- Don't store in the `user` table a FK into the `item` table unless a user can have at most one item.

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    item_id BIGINT UNSIGNED      -- don't do this
  );
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Users - stores user information only, 
Items - stores item information only, 
User_items - Stores userId and itemId

The basic query would be like below, you could then display the results by item. The SELECT * returns all the rows from all the tables. So you would get all the user, item and user_items information.

```
SELECT * FROM user_items
JOIN items on user_items.itemId = items.itemId
WHERE userId = $yourUserID
GROUP BY itemId
```